# Get a wolfram entity value attribute at a time

Tags: wolfram-language

This is something I've always struggled with. Let's say I want to know the population of Mexico City, I can easily do

```
Mexico City ["Population"]
```

[image: Mexico City get attribute Population]

But say I'm making a chart over time and I want to get the population of Mexico City in 1800AD. I understand that not all data is going to be available, but just syntactically, how do I query for that?

Answer (score 0):

I was pointed to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153200/how-to-get-the-us-population-for-every-year-wolfram-has-data-on/153202) which provided the hint I needed.

Seems like confusingly, historical info might not be stored on the proper name entities at all. Instead I had to invoke the `CityData` function

```
CityData[Mexico City, {"Population, All}]
```

[image: Using CityData]

Why this dataset sucks so much is a separate question...